# Setting cookie path as slash (/)

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, subdomain

I'm trying to set cookie from a sub-domain and I succeed. But I cannot set the cookie path to `"/"` .

I'm setting cookie in my jsp page like below

```
  Cookie cookie = new Cookie("IsLoggedIn","true");
  cookie.setDomain(".parent.com");
  cookie.setMaxAge(0);
  cookie.setPath("/");
  response.addCookie(cookie);
  response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

Where this login.jsp in some parent domains  I frame. If you see I'm setting the path as `"/"`, yet getting the cookie path as `/wager-online` , but I need it as

```
"/"
```

See how cookie is getting genrated in below firebug screenshot.

[image]

How can I do that   ??

Comment: Is `/wager-online/` your application's context path?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  Any idea of fixing this ?

Comment: just try with this cookie.setPath("//"); by adding one more slash in the setPath like that. this will point to root domain name only

Answer (score 0):

```
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
```

Set max-age to 0 means remove that cookie. You should set it to a positive integer or use default value.